# How do you make a function that "waits" an x amount of seconds in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make the terminal wait an x numbers of seconds before printing something on screen. I literally copied the code from somewhere else online but my terminal just doesn't wait any time at all and executes everything altogether as it normally would.
Do you guys know why this happens?

```c
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    delay(5);
    printf(". ");
}

void delay(int number_of_seconds)
{
    // Converting time into milli_seconds
    int milli_seconds = 1000 * number_of_seconds;

    // Stroing start time
    clock_t start_time = clock();

    // looping till required time is not acheived
    while (clock() < start_time + milli_seconds)
        ;
}
```

Comment: You need sleep function: https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep. It is a part of so called POSIX standard (you will hear a lot about it all the time), so should be available on any system.

Comment: When using `clock()` please use `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` not `1000`. Milliseconds are system-specific. So `clock_t ticks = CLOCKS_PER_SEC * number_of_seconds;`

Comment: Adding to Weather Vane’s comment, `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is 1,000,000 on my system, so your code would wait 5,000 microseconds or 5 milliseconds. Also, do not do this; it makes the CPU run continuously during the delay, which is wasteful. Use `sleep` or other methods to ask the system to wake your process after time has passed.

Comment: You call an operating system function to sleep  , the answer depends on your OS.

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted. It's a perfectly valid question with an attempt by OP

Comment: Also don't do this beacause clock() only counls time while the CPU is running your code,  if you ran 20 copies sumultanously and only had 10 cores, you'd find that most would wait for about 10 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a "sleep" function, on unistd.h

```
#include <unistd.h>

//something your code

sleep(seconds);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: There is also `usleep()` if you need higher resolution.

Comment: also `nanosleep()`